# Query the particular field value from elasticsearch using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have tried to **query particular field value**(eg.password field and its value) from elasticserach using nodejs
I wish to take this value of the password field (the field value is in encrypted format in elasticsearch index) because to decrypt the value using nodejs.

Comment: What did you do to achieve this?

Comment: I used elasticsearch-odm package to interect with elasticsearch..